# Doubt on the domain of $f(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{e^t}{t}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

Let study the function $f(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{e^t}{t}dt=-\int_{x}^{1}\frac{e^t}{t}dt$. First of all I want to determine the domain.
The integrand function is defined for all $t\neq 0$. This means that $f(x)$ is surely defined for each $x\in(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$, but the fact that $1\in (0,\infty)$ should make me to say that the domain is only $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: yes, the domain is $(0,\infty )$.

Comment: @Surb Thank you very much! So after having found the domain of the integral function have I to verify the maximum interval where the eventual constant lower extreme (in this case 1) is contained, right?

Comment: The integral blows up as $x \to 0^+$, (that the integrand blows up at 0 is necessary but not sufficient, think of $x^{-1/2}$) if the integral converged (say if you replaced $e^t$ in the denominator with $\sin t$) your only problem would be notational. Note  for $t$ positive & close to $0$ the integral is bounded below by $1/t$.

Comment: @GeorgeCoote I have not understood what you mean

Comment: Check my edit? The problem is essentially that the improper integral $\int_0^1 \frac {e^t} t dt$ diverges. Otherwise there would be no problem.

Comment: @GeorgeCoote oh well do you mean that if the integral converges the domain is all $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, if the integral converged, then you could've used it to define a function on $\mathbb R$. See for example $\int_0^x \frac {\sin t} t dt$ and the "Sine Integral" function. Of course this integrand doesn't actually blow up at $0$, perhaps $\int_0^x \frac 1 {\sqrt t} dt = 2 \sqrt x$ (replacing $x$ with $|x|$ if you want all of $\mathbb R$) is a better example for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, since the integrand is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ the (natural) domain of $f$ is $(0,\infty)$.

If we try to extend the domain to include $x=0$ then we get $\displaystyle f(0)=\int_1^0 \frac{e^t}{t}dt=-\int_0^1 \frac{e^t}{t}dt$.  Unfortunately, this integral diverges.

[Reason:  For $t\in(0,1]$, $0< \frac{1}{t}\leq \frac{e^t}{t} $. So $\infty = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{t}dt \leq \int_0^1 \frac{e^t}{t}dt$.]

Comment: Note the reason the domain of this function does not include $0$ (or negative inputs) is *not* because the integrand is undefined at $t=0$ or even becuase the integrand goes to $\infty$ as $t\rightarrow 0$.  @George Coote gives a nice example in the comments above of a function described by an integral for which the integrand goes to $\infty$ as $t \rightarrow 0$.  Namely, $f\displaystyle (x)= \int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{|t|}}dt = 2\sqrt{|x|}\cdot\text{sgn}(x)$.  Notice this function is defined for all $\mathbb{R}$ despite the fact the integrand is undefined (and even goes to infinity) near $0$.

Comment: To emphasize, notice that the domain of $\displaystyle g(x):= \int_1^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{|t|}}dt$ is all real numbers, $(-\infty, \infty)$.  [Reason:  $g(x)=2\sqrt{|x|}\cdot\text{sgn}(x)-2$, since $\displaystyle 2+g(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{|t|}}dt + g(x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{|t|}}dt = 2\sqrt{|x|}\cdot\text{sgn}(x)$.]

Answer (score 1):

*This means that $f(x)$ is surely defined for each $x\in (-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$.*

I wouldn't said so. It can be the case but it is not obvious. Imagin easier situation  $$\tilde{f}(x)=\int_{1}^x\frac{1}{t}\mathrm{d}t$$

Let us try find $\tilde{f}(-1)$. Since this problem is well known I will give you a reference [(see: Improper Integral)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Examples). However you can try to make sense of such things by [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). Then in this specific sense  $\tilde{f}(-1)=0$. Here situation is similar (or very similar) since $e^t\approx 1$ in the small neighborhood of zero. Therefore I would not assume that $\text{dom}(f)=(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$. But if you need to extend $f$ you can do this in the Cauchy principal value spirit as a value of limit $$f(x)=-\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{x}^{-\epsilon}\frac{e^t}{t}\mathrm{d}t + \int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{e^t}{t}\mathrm{d}t$$ for $x<0$.